# c++ is there a default data class for sorted index based acces at reasonable speed?

Tags: c++, sorting, data-structures, queue, priority-queue

I'm looking for a dataclass that keeps its data in order but also allows access in any order I want.

Basically I'm looking for a queue that allows me to access items in a random order as well as remain in order (int lowest to highest). When adding items it should not have to resort everything (O(n*log(n))  operation) but instead just insert and remove it in a fast way (O(log (n))). I know such data structures exist(binary tree based queue) but does c++ offer one? My current applications asks that I can do things like get middle from a queue/list of items or get the second highest priority item. Does c++ have a default data class for this? Or do I have to make it myself?

By the way this is c++ 98

Comment: When you say "that allows me to access items in a random order" do you mean access by index?

Comment: Yes that means access by index (give me the third item)

Comment: If the data type is not expensive to copy, you might find that a vector of them which you sort after insertion is actually faster than a map.

Comment: No, such data structure does not exist. It is rather rare to need such thing. Can you outline the algorithm you need it for? Maybe it can be modified to make it easier to implement.

Comment: Access by index or by key?

Comment: by index (get me the third highest number)

Answer (score 1):

I think the vector plus heap is like what you are looking for.

```
vector<int> v;

// insert elements
v.push_back(3);
push_heap(v.begin(), v.end());

v.push_back(2);
push_heap(v.begin(), v.end());

v.push_back(4);
push_heap(v.begin(), v.end());

// get the second big
sort_heap(v.begin(), v.end());
cout << v[v.size() - 2] << endl;

// insert elements
make_heap(v.begin(), v.end());
v.push_back(7);
push_heap(v.begin(), v.end());

// get the second big
sort_heap(v.begin(), v.end());
cout << v[v.size() - 2] << endl;
```

The insertion is fast. But each time before you want to access item which is not the biggest, you have to sort the heap, since the heap only give you the biggest. And after that and before new insertion you have to call `make_heap` to make the vector a heap again.

Comment: Note however that heap is _not sorted_. It is only adjusted so that the _largest_ (most texts define heap to have the _smallest_ element in root, but C++ has to differ; well, you can always invert the comparison) is in the first, root, element. But the other elements are in semi-random order.

Comment: priority_queue wraps the push_heap, sort_heap, etc functions so you can use that one container to do all of this. The problem with a heap though is that it's only guaranteed that the first element is the largest. The order of the remaining elements is implementation dependant.

Comment: @ScottLangham: Please, read the description to the end: "The range loses its properties as a heap." Not usable after every step.

Comment: @Jan Hudec & Scott Langham, did you notice that description to the end "But each time before you want to access items in random order, you have to sort the heap". "sort_heap" is the key and I think it is not so expensive, because like Jan Hudec said the other elements are in semi-random order. And "sort_heap" is needed only when you want to get element which is not the biggest.

Comment: @Edmund: The problem is that after you call `sort_heap`, you get a sorted array which **is not a heap** (the sort order is reversed). So the algorithm would have to reverse (using O(_n_) operations) the array to go on.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make it yourself.

Create a wrapper around a std::vector. Add methods as required that delegate to the vector, for insert methods, call std::upper_bound to find where to do the insertion.

Comment: Have you noticed the "When adding items it should not have to resort everything (O(n*log(n)) operation)" in the question?

Comment: @Jan Hudec. Ah, yes, sorry!

Comment: However the insert is still O(_n_). Helped a bit but not much.

Comment: Boost has a flat_multi(map)/set containers that implement this: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/container/non_standard_containers.html#container.non_standard_containers.flat_xxx

Comment: Nevertheless it **still has O(_n_) insert** (compared to O(log(_n_)) of map).

Answer (score 0):

No, such structure does not exist in standard library. I don't think it exists in boost either, but looking at [Boost.MultiIndex](http://www.boost.org/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html) wouldn't hurt.

Otherwise such structure is conceptually simple—some kind of balanced search tree (a-b or red-black probably) that additionally needs to maintain number of children in it's nodes (which probably makes a-b tree with higher a and b more suitable than 2-3 or red-black. But there does not seem to be anything to help you implement it.